# How to hide the previous and next numbers in a number picker?

Tags: android, android-number-picker

**Summary**

I'm attempting to hide the previous and next numbers in an Android number picker. Additionally, I'm extending the NumberPicker class so that I can change the font size and color. I've noticed that I could potentially change the value:

```
private static final int MODIFIED_SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT = 3;
```

I'm just not sure how I could override a static final value.

**Default number picker:**

[image: Default Number Picker]

**Desired Modified Number Picker**
I would like to make the number picker look like so, with the animation in tact:

[image: Modified Number Picker]

**Extended Number Picker class:**

```
public class CustomStatNumberPicker extends android.widget.NumberPicker{
    private static final int MODIFIED_SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT = 1;

    public CustomStatNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if(view instanceof EditText){
            ((EditText) view).setTextSize(40);
            ((EditText) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    }

}
```

**TL;DR; How do I hide the previous and next number picker values?** Either through overriding a method, or modifying the extended class like I've already done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you make it? I am also facing this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could modify the drawing routine to skip over any index that isn't in the center row. Try changing the conditions at [line 1478](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker.java#L1478).