# Hide previous/next numbers in a number picker

Tags: android, overriding, android-number-picker

I'm looking to hide the top and bottom numbers in a number picker (Android), so that you only ever see what's inside the 'selected item' area.

I can't seem to figure out how to modify the number picker class to stop it from drawing these numbers. I know this has been asked before, specifically [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495601/how-to-hide-the-previous-and-next-numbers-in-a-number-picker), but the solution isn't shown. I've never had to do a method override, and it's a little confusing.

Thanks